# How to get location of gestureRecognizer in UITableView's frame, not bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

In my subclass of `UITableView` I have a method that is called when long press gesture is recognised:

```
func longPressed(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    let location = recognizer.locationInView(self)
    print("location: \(location), \(frame.origin), \(bounds.origin)")
}
```

And in this case (red circle is where I tapped):

[image]

the console prints:

```
location: (32.0, 277.5), (0.0, 50.0), (0.0, 261.5)
```

So my location is in bounds coordinate? I need an absolute position of touch in UITableView but excluding scroll. Is it possible?

Shortly this is what I expect here less or more:

```
location: \(32.0, 22.0) ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A view’s frame is specified in the superview coordinate system. So you can use:

```
let locationInSuperView = recognizer.locationInView(self.superview)
```

Alternatively you can remove the scroll offset yourself:

```
let contentOffset = self.contentOffset
let location = recognizer.locationInView(self)
let locationWithoutScroll = CGPoint( x: location.x - contentOffset.x,
                                     y: location.y - contentOffset.y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get tableView's cell location on a specific cell.

```
   let location = gesture.location(in: tableView)
   let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location)
   Print(indexPath.row)
   Print(indexPath.section)
```